# Issue with Vertical Spacing in LaTeX Box

Tags: spacing, formatting, tcolorbox

I am currently working on a document in LaTeX and have encountered an issue with the vertical spacing within my custom box environment. I am using the tcolorbox package to create a custom box for certain text sections. However, I've noticed that the vertical spaces above and below the text in the box are not of the same height (indicated by the red and blue arrows in the attached image).[image]

Here is the code snippet I am using for my custom box environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}


\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=white,
    left=\dimexpr\tcboxedtitleheight/2\relax,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=\dimexpr\tcboxedtitleheight/2\relax,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
    },
    top=0mm,
    boxed title style={
        arc=0pt,
        colframe=black,
        colback=black,
        coltitle=white,
        boxrule=1pt,
        right=1.5pt,
        left=1.5pt,
        top=1.5pt,
        bottom=1.5pt,
    },
}

\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\bfseries#1}, before upper={\vspace{\dimexpr\tcboxedtitleheight}}, after upper={\vspace{\dimexpr\tcboxedtitleheight/2}}, before={\vspace{0pt}}, after={\vspace{0pt}}]%
    }{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Complex Numbers}

\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}{Pro\smash{p}erties of the modulus function}
The \textbf{modulus} of a complex number \(z = a + b\mathrm{i}\) is defined as \(\displaystyle{\vert z\vert} = {\sqrt{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}\).
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

The issue seems to stem from the ascenders of certain characters, as well as the descenders, such as the one in the word "complex" and the functions like the square root symbol. I have tried using the \smash command, but the solution is not optimal and requires manual adjustments for every instance.

I have also looked at similar posts on the topic, but none of the solutions presented by others seem to be working for me in this particular context.

Could someone please suggest a more elegant and efficient solution to ensure consistent vertical spacing within my custom box environment? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Here's another code showing just how varied the difference in the top and bottom margins can be depending on what's in the first line. It looks quite ugly, and I just want something that respects vertical symmetry more (see my comments below)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=white,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=\dimexpr\tcboxedtitleheight/2\relax,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
    },
    top=0mm,
    boxed title style={
        arc=0pt,
        colframe=black,
        colback=black,
        coltitle=white,
        boxrule=1pt,
        right=1.5pt,
        left=1.5pt,
        top=1.5pt,
        bottom=1.5pt,
    },
}


\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\bfseries#1}, before upper={\vspace{\dimexpr\tcboxedtitleheight}}]%
    }{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Complex Numbers}

\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}{Pro\smash{p}erties of the modulus function}
The \textbf{modulus} of a complex number \(z = a + b\mathrm{i}\) is defined as \(\displaystyle{\vert z\vert} = {\sqrt{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}\).
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{Pro\smash{p}erties of the modulus function}
The \textbf{modulus} of a complex number \(z = a + b\mathrm{i}\) is defined as \(\displaystyle{\vert z\vert} = {\sqrt{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}\). \lipsum[1] $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x}}$
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{Pro\smash{p}erties of the modulus function}
The \textbf{modulus} of a complex number
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{Pro\smash{p}erties of the modulus function}
The \textbf{modulus} of a complex number $\dfrac{1}{x}$
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for

Comment: It's that way because the radical pushes the text vertically downwards when introduced. If you deleted the radical, the remainder of that text is much more vertically central (between bottom of title box and bottom of main text box). I need the radical in there, though. That's the problem. Smashing the radical does fix most of the issue, but I'd like a more generally applicable solution.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question carefully, you were already aware that the radical was the cause (I therefore deleted those comments). In fact, I think what you have here is consistent spacing, given that the whole line counts (that was meant to be the conclusion after my previous comments...).

Comment: Suppose the radical were near the beginning of that line. If it was ignored, there would be insufficient space there. So ignoring stuff which exceeds the height of the text in general wouldn't be a good solution. To automate it, you'd need to measure the width of the title box, find out whether any too-tall stuff occurred before that point in the line and then adjust or not. I'd think manual adjustment with `\smash` or whatever is what those kinds of commands are for. This probably isn't a good case for an automated approach. What 'looks right' depends on too many factors.

Comment: I understand that. I think what I'm looking for is a style where the first letter of the sentence (T here) is perfectly vertically centered in the text box, and this should always be the case. So if we then add an expression like the radical that requires more space above the line of text, then the same amount of space should be added beneath the line so that the T is still vertically central in that box. Hope some of that makes sense?

Comment: So the content never exceeds the available width? That is, you always have exactly one line of text?

Comment: See the edits I've provided